# Permalinks for WooCommerce Categories and Subcategories

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I found this solution on [stackexchanges](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291018/permalinks-for-woocommerce-categories-and-subcategories) to setup the permalink structure like this

```
Product 1: /shop/category/subcategory/product1/
Product 2: /shop/category/product2/
```

The solution with this code in the function.php works so far for the product and subcategories, they all have now the base url "shop". But parent categories are displaying an 404 page now.

```
 function wpse_291143_generate_taxonomy_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $base = "shop";

    $rules = array();
    $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'hide_empty' => false ));

    foreach($terms as $term) {
        $term_children = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'parent' => intval($term->term_id),
            'hide_empty' => false
            )
        );
        if($term_children) {
            foreach ( $term_children as $term_child ) {
                $rules[$base . '/' . $term->slug . '/' . $term_child->slug . '/?$'] = 'index.php?product_cat=' . $term_child->slug;
            }
        }
    }

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'wpse_291143_generate_taxonomy_rewrite_rules');
```

How can i get this code worked that it also works with the parent categories?

category base: **shop**

Custom base url **/shop/%product_cat%/**

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem finally found the solution here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/same-permalink-for-shop-category-custom-base-with-child-cats/

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', function( $rules ) {
    $new_rules = array();
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
        'post_type'  => 'product',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));
    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        $siteurl = esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $term_slug = $term->slug;
            $baseterm = str_replace( $siteurl, '', get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' ) );
            // rules for a specific category
            $new_rules[$baseterm .'?$'] = 'index.php?product_cat=' . $term_slug;
            // rules for a category pagination
            $new_rules[$baseterm . '/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' ] = 'index.php?product_cat=' . $term_slug . '&paged=$matches[1]';
            $new_rules[$baseterm.'(?:feed/)?(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = 'index.php?product_cat=' . $term_slug . '&feed=$matches[1]';
        }
    }

    return $new_rules + $rules;
} );

/**
 * Flush rewrite rules when create new term
 * need for a new product category rewrite rules
 */
function imp_create_term() {
    flush_rewrite_rules(false);;
}
add_action( 'create_term', 'imp_create_term' );
```